# Right metric type to be used

Tags: prometheus

My Python batch job monitors a shared storage to see if any new artifact has arrived and runs Fortify and Veracode scans against them and I'm capturing the output like below in the `.prom` output file.

```
#1 being success and 0 failure.
artifact_push_status 1 
fortify_run_status 1
veracode_run_status 0
```

I'm not sure, whether I'm using the right metric type here or what should be the right metric type to be used along with the right metric name ?

Push happens every 3 hourly, is there something I can do better to have a better data points over time ?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Could multiple artifacts being pushed between jobs?

Comment: Single artifact is being pushed every 3 hourly (a EAR file). I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your metrics seems fine.

According to [best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/) you could rename them to something like

```bash
# HELP mysystemname_artifact_push_success Status of last attempt to push artifact. 1 - success
# TYPE mysystemname_artifact_push_success gauge
mysystemname_artifact_push_success 1 
# HELP mysystemname_artifact_push_fortify_check_success Status fortify check for last pushed artifact. 1 - success
# TYPE mysystemname_artifact_push_fortify_check_success gauge
mysystemname_artifact_push_fortify_check_success 1
# HELP mysystemname_artifact_push_veracode_check_success ...
# TYPE mysystemname_artifact_push_veracode_check_success gauge
mysystemname_artifact_push_veracode_check_success 0
```

Where `mysystemname` is a placeholder for actual (short) name of your system.

Here all metrics are gauges.

Also, since you are using planning on using texfile exporter, there is now way of know have your job run last time, or is node_exporter serves you old data, I recommend to add one more metric:

```bash
# HELP mysystemname_artifact_push_last_run Unix timestamp of the last run of artifact push job
# TYPE mysystemname_artifact_push_last_run counter
mysystemname_artifact_push_last_run 1395066363
```

This way you'll have a chance to use query `time()-mysystemname_artifact_push_last_run` to see how long job wasn't run.
And maybe alert rule with expression `(time()-mysystemname_artifact_push_last_run) / 60 / 60 > 3`.

Also, if (and only if) your job is not bound to single host, but executed on any available ("service-level" batch job) you might [want to use Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/). If you job is being run on the same host - your current idea of using textfile exporter is the correct one.

Comment: `mysystemname_artifact_push_last_run counter` is a great suggestion or improvement :)
`1395066363` is in seconds, If I'm not wrong ?
Yes, the job is currently running on a single host, may be in future will be ran on two more VMs for redundancy.

Comment: @RafaS, yes it's in seconds. It's epoch timestamp (a.k.a Unix timestamp a.k.a number of secons since 01.01.1970).